# Manual Override Button for Sonoff Basic

Tags: sonoff

I have a sonoff basic R2 v1.0 and looking for a manual override button. I have tried connecting GPIO0 terminals with a momentary switch but doesn't seem to work.

I cannot use GPIO14 as I am using it for PIR sensor inputs.

Any suggestions are appreciated.